# NSPredicate simular un SQL "Select count(distinct nombreColumna)" de un array

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo un Array lleno de 'n' diccionarios. Estos diccionarios tienen los mismos números de campos 'x' campos, con el mismo nombre ( A modo de simular una tabla típica de base de datos). El campo 'B' por ejemplo puede contener un numero o nombre. Deseo conocer cuantos elementos distintos hay de un valor que coincida con el campo 'B' en este Array.

Para seleccionar un campo con un valor lo hago de esta manera,

'NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"B IN %@",@[valor]];'

Pero me devuelve todos los campos ya sean distintos o no. 
¿Como tendría que hacerlo para que me devolviera solo los distintos? ¿ Y luego contarlos ?. Es decir seria hacer algo parecido como en SQL cuando se hace un 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nombreColumna) FROM nombreTabla'

Answer (score 1):

Prueba:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(B != %@)",valor];

NSInteger count = [[ArrayDeDiccionarios filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] count];
```

Este predicado lo que recoge son todas las ocurrencias del Array en las que la key B del json sea distinta de un valor dado.
Luego se le hace un count al array resultante y ahi tienes el numero de ocurrencias distintas.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir alguna explicación sobre qué hace este código?